# Change login text button to logout and vice versa

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the middle of learning React. I have an authentication program using **JWT**, **passport**, and **Redux**. I'm making navbar with bootstrap that filled with Logo, Register button, and login button. I don't understand to change login text button with logout text when a user successfully logged in and ***vice versa*** when successfully logged out. Here's my code in **Dashboard.js**:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "75vh" }} className="container valign-wrapper">
        <div style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }} className="row">
          <div className="landing-copy col s12 center-align">
            <h4>
              <b>Hey there,</b> {user.name}
              <br />
              <br />
              <p className="flow-text grey-text text-darken-1">
                You are logged in!
              </p>
            </h4>
            <button
              style={{
                width: "150px",
                borderRadius: "3px",
                letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                marginTop: "1rem"
              }}
              onClick={this.onLogoutClick}
              className="btn btn-danger"
            >
              Logout
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser })(Dashboard);
```

And the **Navbar.js** code:

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <Link
          to="/"
          style={{
            fontFamily: "monospace"
          }}
          className="navbar-brand"
        >
          REAVOTE
        </Link>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
          <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <Link
              to="/register"
              style={{
                width: "140px",
                borderRadius: "3px",
                letterSpacing: "1.5px"
              }}
              className="btn btn-primary"
            >
              Register
            </Link>
            &ensp;
            <Link
              to="/login"
              style={{
                width: "140px",
                borderRadius: "3px",
                letterSpacing: "1.5px"
              }}
              className="btn btn-danger"
            >
              Log In
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Inside button tags you can have `{user ? "Logout" : "Login"}`. However, the `onClick` function should then first check if user is logged in or not and then do the appropriate action.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you bring auth state from your reducer(mapStateToProps);
And add this to your onClick property to apply two functions for each situation:

```
onClick = {
  this.props.auth.user ? (this.handleLogout) : (this.handleLogin)
}

onLoginClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.logoutUser()
}

onLogoutClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.loginUser()
}
```

And it is better to share your code directly, not a jpg file for readability and copy/paste/share etc

If you want to change the button text do the same check for auth in the button text area:

```
<button style= {{width: "150px", borderRadius: "3px", letterSpacing: "1.5px", marginTop: "1rem"}}
    onClick= {this.onLogoutClick}
    className="btn btn-danger" > {this.props.auth.user ? "Logout": "Login"}
</button>
```

Comment: can you explain me for detail from where I start?

Comment: First, share your code by writing it directly, I mean copy-paste into your question, not with images.

Comment: Is it validate to me "too much code in your question than your explanation"? So I can't publish my post

Comment: No, I mean it is a convention here not to share code with images, it is not useful.

Comment: Had done change the picture with code. Please check

Comment: Check the edited answer, this will direct your login function to logout whether there is auth or not

Comment: Still don't get the answer

Comment: Ok, you have a auth state you stored in your reducer. You bring it to your component by `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});` This is where we can check if there is a user logged in or not. (If he/she is logged in, there WILL BE a user, so the variable this.props.auth.user will be exist. So if it is exist(=it is true) there is an auth. If the auth exist then text should be"Logout" because the user will want to logout in the case of click the button. If there is no auth, then the person trying to login, the text and the function should be "login"

Comment: `{this.props.auth.user ? "Logout": "Login"}` this is a Conditional (ternary) operator. It means exactly this: `if(this.props.auth.user) {"Logout" }else{"Login"}`

Comment: @FebryAryo sorry maybe I couldn't explain very well :)