# How can i redirect to same page for certain routes in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSoZh.png)

i would like to restrict signup page after user is logged in so, if user is logged in then return back to same page

Comment: Please write code, not images of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
def signup_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")
    else:
        return render("signup_page")
```

Another simple way would be to just change the button which redirects to your registration page to something like "profile" and redirect to your profile page:
[Change login text button to logout and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467551/change-login-text-button-to-logout-and-vice-versa)

Comment: thats good to get along thanks

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite well get your question. But you want the new user to signup and when logged in return to signup page or home page?

If you want the logged in user to go to home page when he/she returns without the need to login or registering you can use `redirect()`

Your `views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
def registerPage(request):
form = CustomUserCreationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Account successfuly created!')

        user = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=request.POST['password1'])

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

        next_url = request.GET.get('next')
        if next_url == '' or next_url == None:
            next_url = 'home'
        return redirect(next_url)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'An error has occured with registration')
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```